# Proof that in $\mathbb{R}^+$ the function $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I want to proof that the function $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is continuous in the positive real numbers.
Therefore I use the epsilon delta definition of continuity. But when I make my calculations (to find epsilon in function of delta) I get stuck.

Can anybody help me to go further on $\left| \frac{x-a}{(1-x)(1-a)} \right| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Why do you have $(1-x)(1-a)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Because according to the defintion |f(x)-f(a)| u have $| \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-a}|$ and then make them have the same denominator.

Comment: except the function is $\frac1{1+x},$ not $\frac1{1-x}.$

Comment: Ow sorry quick mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read: $\left|\dfrac{x-a}{(1+x)(1+a)}\right| < |x-a| < \epsilon$ if you let $\delta = \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I see. This is because |1/(1+x)| is less than one for every x of the positive real numbers?

Comment: @notaMathqueen: Yes it is !